# `mkbootfs` command not found while trying to build AOSP kernel

Tags: kernel, aosp

Followed guide here: https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels

```
mkdir android-kernel && cd android-kernel
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b android-msm-bonito-4.9-android11-qpr2
repo sync
build/build.sh
```

It runs for ~7min then fails @

```
Creating initramfs: build/build.sh: line 967: mkbootfs: command not found
```

I found the `mkbootfs` binary, in many locations actually, and all of them, when executed, say "command not found"!

- I tried `chmod 777` & `chmod +x`, but same issue.
- Tried `sudo` as well.
- I tried adding `$HOME/android/aosp-kernel/build/build-tools/path/linux-x86` to my `PATH` but same results.

`build\build.sh` Line 967 is not where the `mkbootfs` cmd is, but it does appear on line 980:

```
mkbootfs "${INITRAMFS_STAGING_DIR}" >"${MODULES_STAGING_DIR}/initramfs.cpio"
```

What is the expected result when `mkbootfs` is run without parameters??

I'd think this would be easy. For some reason, I can't find anything helpful on the net.

Please help.

Comment: What about the system you are building AOSP on? Is it a regular x86_64 Linux PC or something different?

Comment: It is WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.x. I've successfully compiled several ROMs & kernels, LineageOS, without issue, so didn't think much of that. But I did try the mkbootfs binary on a raspberry pi 4 (debian) & still got "command not found".  Is that expected when executed with no parameters? I wouldn't think so.

Comment: You can't transfer a binary from an x86 platform to an ARM[64] platform, that will never work. You should execute `file mkbootfs` on the binary to see for what platform it has been compiled.

Comment: Thank you Robert - you sent me down the right path.  At first I was simply trying to determine HOW to validate the mkbootfs file - in the end, executing it should issue the error: "error: no directories to process?!".  I have no idea why my binaries in my AOSP directory, that compile just fine, dont work.  You actually taught me a few things as well about how to troubleshoot - and in the end, my continued search to find these binaries is what helped me fix it.  Now...how to report this bug to Google!?!

Answer (score 2):

**Issue:**
Cloning the repo doesn't include these folders:

- `/aosp-kernel/prebuilts/build-tools/path/linux-x86/`
- `/aosp-kernel/prebuilts/build-tools/path/linux-x86/bin`
- `/aosp-kernel/prebuilts/kernel-build-tools/linux-x86/bin/[mkbootfs]` (& more)
- (maybe a few more)

Note: kernel-build-tools URL/Repo is on https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/prebuilts/build-tools/+/refs/heads/master/linux-x86/bin/

**Band-aid Fix: (x86 Linux)**

```
cd ~/
mkdir kernel-build-tools
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/prebuilts/build-tools
ls -l kernel-build-tools
```

Add build tools you just downloaded to the path: (this will work as the current user, **NOT SUDO!**)

```
nano ~/.profile
```

Paste the following lines at the end of your `~/.profile` file.

```
# add Kernel tools to path
if [ -d "$HOME/kernel-build-tools/build-tools/linux-x86/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/kernel-build-tools/build-tools/linux-x86/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Refresh your shell environment: `source ~/.profile`

**VALIDATE**: `mkbootfs` -> "error: no directories to process?!" (This is good!)

I was able to compile it after this.  FYI, `~/aosp-kernel/` is where I synced the Android kernel to.

Comment: The procedure above also works for the following error: `"build/build.sh: line 885: soong_zip: command not found"` 