# AOSP Android 11 Kernel build for Pixel3a/Sargo Touchscreen not working

Tags: kernel, vanilla-android, aosp

**Intro:** I had an issue getting the build to compile, but finally got it to successfully build/compile, & installed on my phone, as covered here: [mkbootfs command not found while trying to build aosp kernel](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239240/mkbootfs-command-not-found-while-trying-to-build-aosp-kernel?noredirect=1#comment317565_239240) I followed the guide here: https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels

BUT... I made **NO CHANGES to the kernel** as I want it to work first.  My phone boots fine, but the touchscreen doesnt work!  Am I missing something?

To say it again if I wasn't clear, I have vanilla AOSP Android 11, made no changes, compiled the kernel, flashed it to my phone, and the touchscreen doesnt work.

If I can't figure this out, at least I'm sharing a complete guide on how to build this...without a functional touch screen!

Here's exactly what I did:

**PREREQS:**

```
Unlock bootloader (not covered here)

Install kernel-build-tools (not included in repo for some reason):
cd ~/
mkdir kernel-build-tools
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/prebuilts/build-tools
ls -l kernel-build-tools
nano ~/.profile
Add lines to path: (this will work as current user NOT SUDO!!)
# add Kernel tools to path
if [ -d "$HOME/kernel-build-tools/build-tools/linux-x86/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/kernel-build-tools/build-tools/linux-x86/bin:$PATH"
fi
Refresh environment: source ~/.profile

Install/Setup adb & fastboot
Download adb & fastboot & unzip:
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip
sudo apt-get install unzip
unzip platform-tools-latest-linux.zip -d ~
nano ~/.profile
Add lines:
# add Android SDK platform tools to path
if [ -d "$HOME/platform-tools" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
fi
Update environment: source ~/.profile

Install build tools:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y bc bison build-essential ccache curl flex g++-multilib gcc-multilib git gnupg gperf imagemagick lib32ncurses5-dev lib32readline-dev lib32z1-dev liblz4-tool libncurses5 libncurses5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libssl-dev libxml2 libxml2-utils lzop pngcrush rsync schedtool squashfs-tools xsltproc zip zlib1g-dev

Create build directories:
mkdir -p ~/bin
mkdir -p ~/android/lineage

Install Repo cmd:
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

Fix Python:
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

Configure Git:
git config --global user.email "[email]"
git config --global user.name "[user]"

Turn on Caching to speed up build:
export USE_CCACHE=1
export CCACHE_EXEC=/usr/bin/ccache
ccache -M 25G
```

**STEPS:**

```
AOSP REPO:
cd ~/
mkdir aosp && cd aosp
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-11.0.0_r38 --depth=1
repo sync

AOSP KERNEL REPO:
cd ~/
mkdir aosp-kernel && cd aosp-kernel
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b android-msm-bonito-4.9-android11-qpr2
repo sync

KERNEL CONFIGS: (I did NOT do this; left here for reference for others)
ls -l ~/android/aosp-kernel/build.config -> [symbolic path to actual file]
->~/android/aosp-kernel/private/msm-google/build.config.bonito_no-cfi
Edit this file:
(orig) POST_DEFCONFIG_CMDS="check_defconfig && update_nocfi_config" ->
POST_DEFCONFIG_CMDS="update_nocfi_config"
*Note: This file indicates the kernel config file: bonito_defconfig
Edit & add to: ~/android/aosp-kernel/private/msm-google/arch/arm64/configs/bonito_defconfig
# Kevin added - IPTables TTL support
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_HL=y 
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_HMARK=y
[Need a blank carriage return at bottom!]

BUILD Image.lz4 via AOSP Kernel repo: (I tried both)
build/build.sh
-OR: BUILD_CONFIG=./private/msm-google/build.config.bonito_no-cfi build/build.sh (if you want to specify a different build that the default)

CONVERT Image.lz4->boot.img via AOSP repo:
Copy newly created \aosp-kernel\out\android-msm-pixel-4.9\dist\Image.lz4
-> \aosp\device\google\bonito-kernel\
cd ~/android/aosp
source build/envsetup.sh
Setup device:
lunch aosp_sargo (Just lunch to get device list)
Make only boot image:
m bootimage

FLASH TO PHONE:
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot reboot
```

Comment: Uh `android-msm-bonito-4.9-android11-qpr2` Why are you using a older (beta?) kernel tag? https://groups.google.com/g/android-building/c/aOj7GU1X3JI/m/cArgPnadAwAJ?pli=1

Comment: LOL sounds like youre on to something...I used that because Im new to this :)  I followed the Google guide https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels & they say there to use android-msm-bonito-4.9-android11-qpr2 for Pixel 3a.  Did I read that wrong? Is there a better way to find out this info? Where? Thanks so far!!

Comment: Ah website not updated. Don't know if that is your problem or not. Anyway the Google group in the link of my prior comment is probably the best source (for Nexus/Pixel/AOSP building - anything else is off-topic there).

Comment: BTW how do "I" tell that this is an older beta tag?  I'm not sure what I'm looking at in that link.  Do you happen to know what "branch" I should be using, android-msm-bonito-4.9-android11-qpr3?  And is that the correct repo URL, "repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b BRANCH"? Thanks!

Comment: And looks like I dont have permission to post on there :(

Comment: That thread is the announcement thread from Googlers. Typically releases have no suffix or 'rX' where X is a number. 'qpr3' seems like a beta release. I would also check when the tag was created but that also assumes you are familiar with Android release schedule. You'll need to sign in with a GMail account (and may need approval from admin).

Comment: In https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest/+refs the branch I used appears to be the latest Android11 for bonito (which sargo uses). Again, I'm not sure where else to look, or what I should be using, if I'm using the wrong one...

Comment: Assuming you found this similar but different device notes about touchscreen driver: https://groups.google.com/g/android-building/c/aOj7GU1X3JI/m/MvkGdhlrAwAJ and https://groups.google.com/g/android-building/c/ou630PviyDc

Comment: I didn't see that - WOW, so Google, for their own devices, has a guide how to build a kernel that is incorrect, and known missing/incorrect drivers, for quite some time?! Astonishing. BUT they compile this code & sell these devices, so are they not sharing correctly? I mean why must we download their repo, then make changes just so it works? I'd totally understand if it was a third party device but it's not. Bizaar.

Comment: & I noticed this bad driver on first boot, couldn't go any further...who knows how many other issues there are...is there a place u can download a working recent aosp kernel source for Google devices?!?

Comment: I spent a lot of time on the "solutions" on those links - with a production build its impossible to mount /system as RW so that appears to be a deadend. I also had to first get Magisk/root installed, and navigate the screen with ADB to allow su access from adb shell su...what a waste of time!!

Comment: Just came across this, might be the fix: https://github.com/facebookexperimental/ExtendedAndroidTools/issues/3 in: aosp-kernel\private\msm-google\arch\arm64\configs\bonito_defconfig WHY the heck would Google do that?!? (& how did THEY get it to work on phones on the store shelf?!)

Answer (score 1):

I'd to know how an issue like this still exists, but here's the fix:

**File:** aosp-kernel\private\msm-google\arch\arm64\configs\bonito_defconfig

**Change these to "y"** & rebuild:

`CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_SYNAPTICS_DSX_CORE_v27=m CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_SYNAPTICS_DSX_RMI_DEV_v27=m CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_SYNAPTICS_DSX_FW_UPDATE_v27=m CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_SYNAPTICS_DSX_TEST_REPORTING_v27=m`

Also found here: https://github.com/facebookexperimental/ExtendedAndroidTools/issues/3

Comment: I'm pretty sure this means they were being loaded as separate modules so they could be updated or something. I know this is old, but do you still have the phone around to run `lsmod` on? On a stock build of AOSP, these four modules are listed.